# Function Arguments Passing and Return

Tags: javascript

```
  var foo = {
    bar: function() { return this.baz; },
    baz: 1
  };
  (function(){
    return typeof arguments[0]();
  })(foo.bar);
```

Why does this code return `undefined`?

I would assume `arguments[0]` would hold the `foo.bar`, which is a function. When invoked via `arguments[0]()` it should return the result of the function evaluation in, this case `1`.  Hence, `typeof arguments[0]()` should return "Number" (like `typeof 1`). Instead, it returns `undefined`. Why?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this refer to bar function itself.

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() {return foo.baz; },
    baz:1
  };
  (function(){
    return typeof arguments[0]();
  })(foo.bar);
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/W9Jqb/

Comment: It doesn't. The `this` keyword points to the execution context. In the given example, that's the scope of the anonymous function which calls it. Since that is itself called from the global scope, `this` simply points to the global `window` object.

Comment: Would be embarrassing if we have a lot of functions in this object and we wanted to change the name of the foo:)

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? I thought the question was *"why does this code return `undefined`?"*, not *"Can you help me find an ugly hack to fix this?"*.

Answer (score 8):

To understand why `this` is not a reference to the object on which the function resides, you have to understand that JavaScript doesn't have classes. It has functions.

In JavaScript, functions are never strictly "bound" to objects like they are in classful languages like Java, C#, whatever. A javascript function is just another type, like `string` and `number`, which means that you can pass functions around in variables like any other type. In your example, the function contained in `foo.bar` isn't aware of `foo` at all. It's just a function, minding its own business.

So what does the `this` keyword do? It points to the **execution context**. In your example, you call the function inside `foo.bar` from the global scope (i.e. `window`), so that's what it points to. You can use `apply()` to call the function in the correct scope, but for that you would need access to that scope (in this case, the `foo` object). This negates any of the security advantages of passing along just the function, without the object.

To "fix" this "problem", ECMAScript 5 (the future version of JavaScript) introduces **[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**. This handy function lets you bind a function to a certain execution scope before passing it to another function, like this:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() { return this.baz; },
    baz: 1
};

var callback = foo.bar.bind(foo);

(function(){
    return typeof arguments[0]();
}(callback));
```

Comment: Also, note that `bind()` will actually work in most modern browsers, today: http://jsfiddle.net/54dzA/. Except we can't use it yet, because IE 6 doesn't support it. Or IE 7. Or IE 8.

Answer (score 5):

the code won't work because inside the anonymous function you lose the reference to `this.baz` of foo object when used in another context

you can use the `apply()` method to redefine the context, like so

```
var foo = {
   bar: function() { return this.baz; },
   baz: 1
};

(function(){
   return arguments[0].apply(foo);
})(foo.bar);
```

and this returns correctly `1` because apply() method change the execution context to the object passed as argument

```
typeof arguments[0].apply(foo);
```

returns `number`as expected

Comment: return typeof arguments[0].apply(foo);I guess this was what you meant. I see the handiness of apply and significance of execution context coming into picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can reffering to foo by `this` statement.

You should write a wrapper like below which will very helpfull if will we wanted to change the name of the foo when we will have a lot of function in foo

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() { return this.baz; },
    baz: 1
  };

(function(a){
 for( var i in a){ 
    if( typeof a[i] === "function" ){

      a[i] = (function(f){  
            return function(){
                return f.apply(a,arguments);
            }
      })(a[i])
    }
 }
})(foo);

  (function(){
    return typeof arguments[0]();
  })(foo.bar);
```