# This Javascript code returns 'Undefined'

Tags: javascript, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function Arguments Passing and Return](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587945/298479)

I need a little help with this

```
 var foo = {
     bar: function () {
         return this.baz;
     },
     baz: 1
 };
 (function () {
     return typeof arguments[0]();
 })(foo.bar);
```

This snippet when executed returns 'undefined'
Can someone please explain why is this so ?

Comment: Hmmmm, I have seen this exact snippet before on SO...

Comment: @leppie with google I found this http://stackoverflow.com/q/8587730/995876 :P How sad that the accepted answer there is incorrect :X

Comment: @Esailija: That's not even the one I recall! It was a week or 2 ago.

Comment: @Esailija - Good find! Completely identical. This question should be closed, even if the accepted answer in the duplicate is incorrect.

Comment: @JamesAllardice the code in the questions is actually from [perfection kills quiz](http://perfectionkills.com/javascript-quiz/), question 6

Comment: @Esailija - Ahh, yeah I guessed it must be from somewhere popular. Good find nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right scope for the call.  Explicitly setting foo as the scope gives the expected result.

```
var foo = {
    bar: function () {
        return this.baz;
    },
    baz: 1
};
(function () {
    return arguments[0].call(foo);
})(foo.bar);
```